# Issue in Spring security when i try to extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring

Am developing a spring security project,and am using spring latest version 3.1.1,and
am trying to extends the WebsecurityConfigurerAdapter,but its not working it is throwing errors.

what should i do to solve this problem?

Comment: Post the stacktrace? Also, WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter has been deprecated and completely removed in the latest version of Spring. You shouldn't use it.